# OpenGL GLSL Shadows not working correctly

Tags: opengl, mapping, glsl, shader, shadow

I`m trying to implement shadowmaps in Java/OpenGL with GLSL.
It seems to be impossible to create shadow maps with Java/OpenGL, there is almost no working example with perspective projection.

What I think is, that the matrix calculation isnt working well.

Here is my shadow result (camera view/proj = shadow view/proj):
[image]

And here I have mapped the linearized depth buffer on a rectangle, its a little bit rotated:
[image]

It seems like the depth buffer is flipped, because on every surface I have mapped it, it is x or/and y flipped. But maybe its just a UV bug.

So the major question is: Can you give me a hint what may happened?

Here are some code snippets:

Final Shader: Depth & Shadow calculation (uSamplerShadow is sampler2D)

```
float shadowValue=0.0;
vec4 lightVertexPosition2=vShadowCoord;
lightVertexPosition2/=lightVertexPosition2.w;
for(float x=-0.001;x<=0.001;x+=0.0005)
    for(float y=-0.001;y<=0.001;y+=0.0005)
    {
        if(texture2D(uSamplerShadow,lightVertexPosition2.xy+vec2(x,y)).r>=lightVertexPosition2.z)
            shadowValue+=1.0;
    }
shadowValue/=16.0;

float f = 100.0;
float n = 0.1;
float z = (2 * n) / (f + n - texture2D(uSamplerShadow,vTexCoords).x * (f - n));

outColor = vec4(vec3(z) , 1.0);
```

Final Shader: Shadow coord calulation: (No bias matrix implemented yet)

```
vShadowCoord = uProjectionMatrix * uShadowViewMatrix * uWorldMatrix * vec4(aPosition,1.0);
```

Depth Shader

```
fragmentdepth = gl_FragCoord.z;
```

You can check my texture properties too, but I have already tried all combinations I found in on google :)

```
            shadowTextureProperties.setMagFilter(EnumTextureFilter.NEAREST);
    shadowTextureProperties.setMinFilter(EnumTextureFilter.NEAREST);
    shadowTextureProperties.setWrapS(EnumTextureWrap.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    shadowTextureProperties.setWrapT(EnumTextureWrap.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    shadowTextureProperties.setInternalColorFormat(EnumTextureColorFormat.DEPTH_COMPONENT16);
    shadowTextureProperties.setSrcColorFormat(EnumTextureColorFormat.DEPTH_COMPONENT);
    shadowTextureProperties.setValueFormat(EnumValueFormat.FLOAT);
    shadowTextureProperties.setPname(new int[]{GL14.GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, GL14.GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC});
    shadowTextureProperties.setParam(new int[]{GL11.GL_NONE, GL11.GL_LEQUAL});
```

Comment: The way you are trying to interpolate shadows is technically wrong, but that doesn't explain why everything is black. This could be because you have no bias and no bias matrix, try googling shadowmap bias for why you need it. Basically subtract a small value from lightVertexPosition2.z in the compare statement, and shift the coordinates around. I'm a bit rusty on this so you'll have to trust google. Try following a single shadowmap tutorial instead of taking a blind stab. You're almost there though, GJ.

Answer (score 0):

First thing:

```
shadowTextureProperties.setPname(new int[]{GL14.GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, GL14.GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC});
```

`GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC` is not a valid parameter for `GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE`. According to the [reference](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glTexParameter.xml), only `GL_NONE` and `GL_COMPARE_R_TO_TEXTURE` are allowed.

**GL_COMPARE_R_TO_TEXTURE**

One has to use a shadow sampler (`sampler2DShadow`) and the corresponding `texture` overload:

```
float texture( sampler2DShadow sampler, vec3 P)
```

Here, the sampler is sampled at location P.xy and the read value is compared to P.z. The result of this operation is a lightning factor (0.0 when completely shadowed, 1.0 when no shadow).

**GL_NONE**

When you want to do the comparison yourself, then you have to set the `GL_COMPARE_R_TO_TEXTURE` to `GL_NONE`

Comment: I don't think it works this way. It looks like the API to set these parameters takes two separate arrays. `setPname (...)` is basically the key and `setParam (...)` is the value. If you line both of those arrays up they work. It's pretty pointless to set `GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC` to `GL_LEQUAL` when `GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE` is set to `GL_NONE`, but that's another matter entirely.